# Switch mapping Realm objects from Main to Background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, realm, rx-java2

I use original Realm wrapper for RxJava. In this way:

```
Flowable<RealmResult<RealmUser> result =
realm.where(RealmUser.class)
.findAllAsync()
.asFlowable();
```

Data are loaded on Realm Background thread and emitted to Main thread.
My problem is that I need to map large amount of Realm object to own POJO (independent business layer). Realm objects can not be passed between threads. It means that I must map objects on Main thread which is undesirable and blocks Main thread. Do you know to perform mapping on background thread and use similar way? Is possible emits unmanaged copy of RealmResult (on Background thread directly from Realm)? I can not find similar way.

Usage of copyFromRealm is not good choice, becasue result is same as in case of my custom mapping.

At this time I use new model class for users only with attributech which I need. Result is lower time of mapping, but on Main thread which cause UI artifacts.

Thanks

Comment: A possible option is to use my library I made called [Monarchy](https://github.com/Zhuinden/realm-monarchy/blob/c65b2ad3a9bfcf1d356ab7be66d4ddce9f3781e9/monarchy-example/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/monarchyexample/features/mapped_rx/MappedRxFragment.java#L67-L69), which exposes the data as LiveData, observes query changes on background thread, and allows mapping on said background thread.

Comment: Why don't you just switch to another scheduler with observeOn and map your models, then you can consume them on main thread again

Comment: @elmorabea please read my question again. You revert what I need. RealmResult can not be switched to different thread (from main to background).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to micro-manage the existence of a background looper thread on which you actually execute your queries:

```
private Observable<List<User>> createResults() {
    return Observable.create((ObservableOnSubscribe<List<User>>) emitter -> {
        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        final RealmResults<RealmUser> results = realm.where(RealmUser.class).findAllAsync();

        final RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<RealmUser>> realmChangeListener = element -> {
            if(element.isLoaded() && !emitter.isDisposed()) {
                List<User> users = mapFrom(element);
                if(!emitter.isDisposed()) {
                    emitter.onNext(users);
                }
            }
        };
        emitter.setDisposable(Disposables.fromAction(() -> {
            if(results.isValid()) {
                results.removeChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
            }
            realm.close();
        }));
        results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
    }).subscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler()).unsubscribeOn(looperScheduler.getScheduler());
}
```

Then you can do the following short-cut, although it evaluates your query twice:

```
Flowable<RealmResult<RealmUser> result =
    realm.where(RealmUser.class)
         .findAllAsync()
         .asFlowable()
         .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .unsubscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .filter(RealmResults::isLoaded)
         .observeOn(Schedulers.from(singleThreadedExecutor))
         .map((ignored) -> {
             RealmConfiguration configuration = realm.getConfiguration();
             try(Realm realm = Realm.getInstance(configuration)) {
                 RealmResults<RealmUser> results = realm.where(RealmUser.class).findAll();
                 return mapToUsersList(results);
             }
         })
         .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
         .subscribe((users) -> { ...
```

Comment: What is looperScheduler in first example?

Comment: `AndroidSchedulers.from(handlerThread.getLooper())` pretty much, but you can check out the [full source code where I got this from](https://github.com/Zhuinden/simple-stack/blob/e1720066f770bd44e96829bfe269b314fab4f097/simple-stack-example-mvp-fragments/src/main/java/com/zhuinden/simplestackdemoexamplefragments/data/repository/TaskRepository.java#L84)